# Actinic Webgains

Tags: actinic

Issue is with the variables in version 7 of Actinic. This code works fine with version 10 of Actinic. Webgains gets the info but does not get the order number or the order total.

I think it is to do with the variables TheOrderNumber and NumericOrderTotal.

```
<!-- <webgains tracking code> -->

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


var wgOrderReference = "TheOrderNumber";

var wgOrderValue = "NumericOrderTotal";

var wgEventID = 10363;

var wgComment = "";

var wgLang = "en_EN";

var wgsLang = "javascript-client";

var wgVersion = "1.2";

var wgProgramID = 6455;

var wgSubDomain = "track";

var wgCheckSum = "";

var wgItems = "";

var wgVoucherCode = "";

var wgCustomerID = "";

var wgCurrency = "GBP";


if(location.protocol.toLowerCase() == "https:") wgProtocol="https";

else wgProtocol = "http";


wgUri = wgProtocol + "://" + wgSubDomain + ".webgains.com/transaction.html" + "?wgver=" + wgVersion + "&wgprotocol=" + wgProtocol + "&wgsubdomain=" + wgSubDomain + "&wgslang=" + wgsLang + "&wglang=" + wgLang + "&wgprogramid=" + wgProgramID + "&wgeventid=" + wgEventID + "&wgvalue=" + wgOrderValue + "&wgchecksum=" + wgCheckSum + "&wgorderreference="  + wgOrderReference + "&wgcomment=" + escape(wgComment) + "&wglocation=" + escape(document.referrer) + "&wgitems=" + escape(wgItems) + "&wgcustomerid=" + escape(wgCustomerID) + "&wgvouchercode=" + escape(wgVoucherCode) + "&wgCurrency=" + escape(wgCurrency);

document.write('<sc'+'ript language="JavaScript"  type="text/javascript" src="'+wgUri+'"></sc'+'ript>');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 7 of Actinic still uses the older way of using variables so you need to use NETQUOTEVAR:THEORDERNUMBER and NETQUOTEVAR:ACTINICORDERTOTAL.

You will need to divide NETQUOTEVAR:ACTINICORDERTOTAL by 100 if you are using it so :

```
var realPrice = NETQUOTEVAR:ACTINICORDERTOTAL / 100;

var wgOrderReference = "NETQUOTEVAR:THEORDERNUMBER";
var wgOrderValue = String(realPrice);
```

This won't work in the no script version you can add in the order reference but can't add in the total.

Answer (score 0):

The no Script tag will also need updating with these variables :)

```
<noscript>
<img src="http://track.webgains.com/transaction.html?wgver=1.2&wgprogramid=6455&wgrs=1&wgvalue=NETQUOTEVAR:NUMERICORDERTOTALCGI&wgeventid=10363&wgorderreference=NETQUOTEVAR:THEORDERNUMBER&wgitems=&wgvouchercode=&wgcustomerid=&wgCurrency=GBP" alt="" />
</noscript>
```